# Check and delete hidden characters in file

Tags: oracle, plsql, non-ascii-characters

I had a file that I was processing and it was constantly giving me errors. After some checking I realized that it had some special characters that were hidden.

I have just manually found the hidden characters and made a simple replace like

```
REPLACE( String,'ï»¿', '')
```

How could I prevent this from happening in the future?

I have tried to make a table that stores these hidden ascii characters which are in the range from *125-255* but the database does not store them accordingly. 
For example **`chr(168)`**  is not the same as `ascii 168`.

```
select chr('168'), 
       convert(chr('168'), 
       'US7ASCII', 
       'WE8ISO8859P1') 
from dual;
```

What else can I try?

Comment: If `REPLACE` worked like that, it means you had those three characters in succession. The better approach to delete individual symbols is to use `TRANSLATE`. `TRANSLATE` is weird, it will return null if the third arguments is null; so you need something like this to remove all digits: `TRANSLATE( string, '~0123456789', '~'). This will translate '~' to itself and all digits to null, therefore removing them. In your case, you need to include the "special characters" instead of digits, IF YOU KNOW WHAT THEY ARE. Are you sure they should all be removed, though?

Comment: You get `ï»¿` typically when you have a UTF-8 text with [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) but this text is treated as encoded at Windows Codepage 1252 - which is cause by wrong settings most likely in your client.

Comment: @mathguy Yes, I want them all to be removed because my program cannot further process the file. However, I do not know if some other time those special characters will remain the same. Because the file is given to me as input from another program, whose code I cannot see, just the output file. So I need to remove every recurrence of the special characters from ascii 125-255. This is where I need help.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit thank you that helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy to write, but not the fastest to execute - using regexp_replace:

```
update table_name
set column_name = 
             regexp_replace(column_name, '[' || chr(125) || '-' || chr(255) || ']', '')
;
```

More efficient, but a pain in the neck to write and maintain (you can write some code to generate the code though, to save some typing):

```
...
set column_name = 
           translate(column_name, '~' || chr(125) || chr(126) || ..... || chr(255), '~')
;
```

Yes, with `translate()` you will have to spell them all out, no "range" concept...  {:-(

That's to change the data already in the tables. It would be even better to fix the data as it is coming in, if you can - using a similar transformation.